# How to calculate values in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I'm working on an application like Food Panda. I'm m facing an issue. I'm calculating driver payouts (e.g. if a driver earns 4.3 dollars per order) I'm trying to get the sum for every month but my code assigning same value to these months when driver was out of service.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong my code:

```js
parameters: toDate=2020-10-21&fromDate=2021-11-21

const resturantOrders = await DelivigoOrder.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "Id",
    "OrderNumber",
    "OrderStatusId",
    "TotalPrice",
    "OrderAcceptTime",
    "DriverId",
    "ResturentId"
  ],
  where: {
    DriverId: driverId,
    IsActive: true,
    // OrderAcceptTime: { [Op.between]: [fromDate, toDate] },
    $or: [
      { OrderStatusId: 50 },
      { OrderStatusId: 55 },
      { OrderStatusId: 60 },
      { OrderStatusId: 70 },
      { OrderStatusId: 80 },
    ],
  },
});

var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct ", "Nov ", "Dec"];

var orderPayouts = [];
let payout = 0;
for (let index = 0; index < months.length; index++) {
  const element = months[index];

  for (let index = 0; index < resturantOrders.length; index++) {
    const order = resturantOrders[index];

    if (element === InternalServices.getMonthName(order.OrderAcceptTime)) {
      console.log(element, index, "in");
      payout = payout + 4.3;
    }
  }

  orderPayouts.push({
    month: element,
    payout: payout
  });
};
```

#### Output

```json
{
  "result": [{
    "month": "Jan",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Feb",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Mar",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Apr",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "May",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Jun",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Jul",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Aug",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Sep",
    "payout": 55.899999999999984
  }, {
    "month": "Oct",
    "payout": 150.5
  }, {
    "month": "Nov",
    "payout": 150.5
  }, {
    "month": "Dec",
    "payout": 150.5
  }]
}
```

driver works in just two months Jan and Oct but my code assing the Jan value to all other months same with OCT.

Comment: You declare `ley payout` outside of the loop. You should consider declaring it INSIDE the loop

Comment: whats the output of restaurantOrders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `ley payout` outside of the loop. You should consider declaring it INSIDE the loop

```
...
for (let index = 0; index < months.length; index++) {
  let payout = 0;
  const element = months[index];
...
```

Comment: thanks again for your reply.